# String paster for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, productivity, user-interface

I'm looking for a small program that will be able to keep and paste (or replace) things I type into a GUI application (like a browser).

## For Example

1. I hit a key combination
2. Some sort of list with a filter comes up and I can find what I want to paste in (a smiley, a unicode character, a URL, whatever).
3. I click on it (or hit ENTER with it selected or whatever), and it's pasted into the active window, or into clipboard.

#### Or an alternative workflow:

1. I type something like "I approve :checkmark:"
2. I hit a key combination (perhaps with the whole sentence selected)
3. String gets replaced with "I approve ✓".

I remember having one of those on Windows, but I'm specficially looking something that will work on Linux (I'm currently running Ubuntu with Unity).

Would appreciate all suggestions and recommendations.

If more details are required, please feel free to yell at me in the comments (It's my first question here :D)

Comment: This should fall under the heading of [input methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) (or at least that's one way to look at it). What desktop environment or window manager do you use (e.g. Unity, Gnome, KDE, LXDE, ratpoison, …)? That's more important than the distribution.

Comment: I'm using Unity, I'll include that in my question.

Comment: [AutoKey](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/autokey-gtk/) would have been the solution, but it is widely reported to be borked in current versions of Ubuntu (a quick websearch will tell you more). [Actionaz](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/actionaz/) appears to be maintained and do what you want. I've never used either of these, but used to use something called [Windows PowerPro](http://powerpro.cresadu.com/) -- a great program -- back in the olden days that included this facility as one of its features. Very handy!